# Avoiding apply when acting on a pandas Series containing a list of json objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains a column (`in_stock_change_history_list`) that is a list of json objects as follows:

```
[{'in_stock': False, 'change_detect_time': '2022-05-02T19:00:04.666994'}]
```

Some rows have just one json blob in the list, and others have more than 1.

I'm adding a new column to the df by using `apply` along with the `calculate_product_stock_outs` method below:

```
menu_products_df['stock_outs'] = menu_products_df['in_stock_change_history_list'].progress_apply(
            self.calculate_product_stock_outs)
```

```
    def calculate_product_stock_outs(self, in_stock_change_history_list):
        in_stock_change_list_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(in_stock_change_history_list)
        in_stock_change_list_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(in_stock_change_list_df.change_detect_time)
        in_stock_change_list_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

        start = in_stock_change_list_df.change_detect_time >= self.start
        end = in_stock_change_list_df.change_detect_time <= self.end

        new_df = in_stock_change_list_df.loc[start & end]
        return new_df[new_df.in_stock == False].value_counts().size
```

This becomes very slow when iterating over 1000s of rows, so I was hoping there might be a way to avoid using `apply` in this case.

Is this a case where using `apply` is unavoidable? Is there a way for me to perform these types of operations directly on the list[jsonb] column?

Comment: The *may be* faster ways that avoid `apply` but I want you to optimize the `calculate_product_stock_outs` function. You create a dataframe for filtering items items in the list that have `in_stock == False` and between `self.start` and `self.end`. You don't need a dataframe for that. A simple loop over the array will do. `apply` is slow, but for a few thousand rows, it may not be so bad if written properly

Comment: @CodeDifferent you were totally right, way faster after refactoring `calculate_product_stock_outs` to not use a dataframe. Appreciate your help here!